# Android icons in xml

Tags: android, xml, icons

I used predefined activity drawer, and it gave me icon in such a format as this:

```
`<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M4,6H2v14c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h14v-2H4V6zm16,-4H8c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v12c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h12c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2V4c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zm-8,12.5v-9l6,4.5 -6,4.5z" />
</vector>
```

`
Earlier I used icons in png in several options (for lowdp,hdpi etc). What is the advantage of using this style of icons? How to create icons in this way?

Best regards

Dominik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Advantages of SVG :-**

- Less size
- Good quality of image
- Easy to change color
- Easy to  change size

Eg:- change width `android:width="24dp"`

Change color   `android:fillColor="#FF000000"`

Comment: To avoid confusion, remember this is _not_ SVG. This is a VectorDrawable, it's based on SVG, but it's Androids version.

Answer (score 1):

try with this way

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: 'android:pathData="M4,6H2v14c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h14v-2H4V6zm16,-4H8c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v12c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h12c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2V4c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zm-8,12.5v-9l6,4.5 -6,4.5z" ' Can you explain me what does that mean? How to prepare icon displayed in that way?

Comment: i unable to find what  you want exactly.

Comment: hmm... i do not know what mean that pathData i mean what that mean what is just after "=".